# Drupal exposed filter not displaying as select/drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-exposed-filter

After a series of updates, including jQuery Update, the select/drop-down fields for my exposed filter has stopped working. It **does** work when I choose the default Drupal jQuery version (which appears to be 1.4); however, other modules don't function with that version.

[Here's a screenshot of what I get now.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8786162/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-25%20at%2011.58.13%20PM.png)

Under "Filter By" there should be two select/drop-down fields for date and topic.

Any ideas?

Comment: in hook_views_pre_view you can remove the latest version of jQuery and add your version of jQuery (1.4 version)

Comment: How would I go about that? This is what I have...

`function hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  // Change the display if the acting user has 'administer site configuration'
  // permission, to display something radically different.
  // (Note that this is not necessarily the best way to solve that task. Feel
  // free to contribute another example!)
  if (
    $view->name == 'my_special_view' &&
    user_access('administer site configuration') &&
    $display_id == 'public_display'
  ) {
    $view->set_display('private_display');
  }
}`